# Access a content type and its data from Drupal database

Tags: drupal, drupal-7

I have this Drupal 7 site that had a form collecting data from unregistered users. All data collected belongs to a content type named "Registration" with 18 fields.

Now I was looking into the database and found that this data is stored in separate tables and not in one like I was hoping for.

I need to display this data (all from "Registration" content type) on an external PHP application. Is there an easy way to access this data?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/views) module and [Views Datasource](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_datasource)(views_json) or You can use [Services](https://www.drupal.org/project/services), [Services Views](https://www.drupal.org/project/services_views) modules to create a JSON API page to get all the Registration content type fields. Then by using curl make a GET request to the JSON API page and you can get all the values in JSON format. :)